# How to display a parameter from two related Eloquent models?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two related Eloquent table models:

```php
# app/Order.php

protected $fillable = [
  'id',  'status', 'client_email', 'partner_id',
];

public function partner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Partner');
}
```

```php
# app/Partner.php

protected $fillable = ['id', 'email', 'name'];

public function order()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Order');
}
```

Then if I try add `$partner` to the array in my `Order` resource , I get a server error:

```
# app/Http/Resources/Order.php

public function toArray($request)
{
   // $partner = Order::find(1)->partner;

    return parent::toArray($request);

    return [
      'id' => $this->id,
      'status' => $this->status,
      'client_email' => $this->client_email,
      'partner_id' => $this->partner->id,
      'partner_name' => $this->partner->name,
     ];
}
```

created additional, but I don't know if I need it or not
app/Http/Resources/Partner.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Partner extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);

        return [
          'id' => $this->id,
          'name' => $this->name,
       ];
    }
}
```

How do I return 'partner_name' to `OrderController` for later use in Vue?

```php
# OrderController.php

use App\Http\Resources\Order as OrderResource;

class OrderController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::with('partner')->get();

        return OrderResource::collection($orders);
    }
}
```

Table partners columns:

```
id, email, name
```

Table orders columns:

```
id, status, client_email, partner_id
```

Is it correct to pass 'partner_name' to the Resources/Order array.php or does it need to be done in the controller?

Please show me how to do this correctly

Comment: try this adding column on the hasone method  return $this->hasOne('App\Passport', 'username', 'username');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your relationships are a little bit off.

From your `$fillable` values in the `Order` model, I can see the `partner_id`, so -correct me if I'm wrong but- that is the foreign key.. making this model the child one.

Try updating your relations like so:

```
# Order.php

public function partner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Partner');
}   //            ^^^^^^^^^
```

And:

```
# Partner.php

public function order()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Order');
}   //            ^^^^^^^
```

So, now you could make your relationship work like so in your `Order` resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Order extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'           => $this->id,
            'status'       => $this->status,
            'client_email' => $this->client_email,
            'partner_id'   => $this->partner_id,
            'partner_name' => $this->partner->name,   // <---
        ];

    }
}
```

---

As a sidenote, given the fact that you want to use this Resource to return several models, when the resource will try to access the relationship value it will make an additional query.. the famous [N+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping). To avoid it, just [eager load the relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) in your controller:

```
use App\Http\Resources\Order as OrderResource;

public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::with('partner')->get();
    //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return OrderResource::collection($orders);
}
```

Comment: good catch on the relationship.  `partner_id` is on the `Order` model, so naturally it `belongsTo`.  (and apparently I'm not allowed to say "+1")

Comment: @Kenny all your edits don't return an error, but neither does `partner_name`. other data is displayed

Comment: @algebra could you update your post with your current code and also your tables structure? There's something missing there. This should work as expected.

Comment: @Kenny I update my post, as you requested. please take a look

Comment: @algebra I've fixed the format of your post. Now, as tt stands, I can see two return statements in your `OrderResource`. The first one is returning the `$order` just casted as array (so, the `partner_name` won't be returned). Remove the `return parent::toArray($request);` and check again if now is returning the expected attributes.

Comment: @algebra also, I've updated my answer including the full code of the `Order` resource.

Comment: @Kenny Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Access `partner` attributes using the relationship from your model in the resource:

```php
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'status' => $this->status,
    'client_email' => $this->client_email,
    'partner_id' => $this->partner->id,       // <-- here
    'partner_name' => $this->partner->name,   // <-- here
];
```

### EDIT:

In your controller, pass in exactly the data you want to use/transform. In your case, you're passing in a collection of `User`.  You also need to pass in any relationships you are relying on.

```php
return App\OrderResource::collection(Order::with('partner')->get());
```

Comment: if I uncomment "$partner = Order::find(1)->partner; " - error. If I only change two lines to yours, nothing changes

Comment: I edited the response.  Seems you're not passing in the related model when you call the `Resource`.